# How to copy only certain elements of one Array to another in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am struggling to create an array with the correct size according to my parameters I have set up. Long story short this program is dealing with a set number of elements in the first array. Those elements are as follows

```
int [] myWeights = {258, 58, 209, 91, 79, 182, 172, 27, 7, 29, 128, 198};
```

Now those elements are in ounces. I get the program to run everything correctly, now my professor wants us to separate the ones that are over 8 pounds into a new array. Those elements in the new array in this case are 258, 209, 182, 172, and 198. The problem is that the program, at the beginning, can create a randomly sized array with varying sized elements between the numbers 1-320. Is there a way to have some sort of loop instantiate the proper amount of "boxes" needed. Or am I just supposed to instantiate some arbitrary number and hope that is what I will need? My current code for this is

```
public static int [] overGivenPounds(int x, int [] array){
    int pounds = 0;
    int arrayLength = 0;
    int arrayOverEightPounds[];
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        pounds = array[i] / 16;

        if(x < pounds){
            arrayOverEightPounds[k] = array[i];
            k++;         

        }
    }
    return arrayOverEightPounds;
```

If any of this seems unclear please ask, there is no need to be rude. I am very new to Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use a loop to determine the size of the target array
2. Create the target array of the needed size
3. Use a second loop to put values in the target array

Without that first step, you cannot know the right size of the array. If you create an array that's even one element too small or one element two big, that will be a waste,
because you will be forced to create a 3rd array to return an array of the right size.

So your solution should look something like:

```
public static int[] overGivenPounds(int x, int[] array) {
    int size = 0;

    for (int value : array) {
        if (satisfies(x, value)) {
            size++;
        }
    }

    int[] result = new int[size];
    // ??? -> for you to complete this
    for (int value : array) {
        if (satisfies(x, value)) {
            // ??? -> for you to complete this
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to use Java streams? If so, the solution would be:

```
return Arrays.stream(myWeights).filter(n -> n/16 > x).toArray();
```

If not then you could use `Arrays.copyOf`to create an array of the correct length:

```
int[] heavyWeights = int[myWeights.length];
int size = 0;
for (int weight: myWeights)
    if (weight / 16 > x)
        heavyWeights[size++] = weight;
return Arrays.copyOf(heavyWeights, size);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int[] overGivenPounds(int x, int[] array){        
    Arrays.sort(array);
    boolean foundSomething = false;
    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {        
        if(array[i]/16>=x){
            startIndex = i;
            foundSomething = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(foundSomething)
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, startIndex, array.length);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do it is to create an array that you know can hold everything, add your items to that array, while keeping track of how many items you have added. At the end you return a copy of the array, truncated to the number of items.

Or, with Java 8, you can write it as a stream one-liner:

```
return Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> (i / 16) > x).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use other classes? If so, you could just use an ArrayList and then use

```
//int arrayOverEightPounds[];
List<Integer> listOverEightPounds = new ArrayList<>();

//...

    //arrayOverEightPounds[k] = array[i];
    listOverEightPounds.add(array[i]);

//....

return listOverEightPounds.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

to return an array of the proper size. In this case you can get rid of `k`. ArrayList uses an array internally but will resize it automatically if it needs more space so you don't have to do that micro-management. The toArray method on ArrayList will return a new array of the proper size if the array that's passed in is not big enough. A common thing you see is to just pass in an array of size 0 into toArray which means the returned value will always be the correctly sized array.

Comment: I don't think so, because this looks like its exactly what I am looking for. Are you able to elaborate more with my code or specific examples? I am unfamiliar about these other ways of doing it.

Comment: I assume not based on "wants us to separate the ones that are over 8 pounds into a new **array**"

Comment: @DylanKelemen Edited.

Comment: If you're assuming `Integer[]` is a valid return type, why not assume `List<Integer>` is valid?